# What does "drop the beat" mean?

Tags: meaning

From Yahoo answers and other sources I could find, it is suggested this means that the beat of the song changes, however when it is mentioned in song lyrics it is usually mentioned as something someone does e.g.

> Beastie Boys known to let the beat, mmm,  drop!

...

> Will.i.am drop the beat now

What is someone doing when they "drop the beat"?

Comment: It used to tell the DJ to drop the needle on the record. Therefore the music begins. Now it just tells people to press the "Play" button or "Enter" key on the computer.

Answer (score 11):

The Rap Dictionary defines the verb [*drop*](http://www.rapdict.org/Drop):

> 3. To play music, or sing a song, could mean for the dj or mixer to add bass behind the singers vocals. ***Drop*** the beat.

and defines the noun *[beat](http://www.rapdict.org/Beat)*:

> 1. Music which is played in the background.

Much of hip-hop has beats played from vinyl records on two turntables, which is rapped over. The instruction to "drop the beat" is from the rapper to the DJ, to start playing a beat or music. *Drop* probably stems from the physical act of dropping or placing a record on the turntable, or more precisely dropping or placing the needle on the record.

The line "Beastie Boys known to let the beat... mmm, drop!" is from their 1998 track, "Intergalactic":

> Tammy D getting biz on the crop
>   Beastie Boys known to let the beat... mmm, drop
>   When I wrote graffiti my name was Slop

If you listen from the [2:27 mark](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVgtEl_83HA#t=2m27s), you can hear a beat under the first line, then no beat at all for the next one, and then a new beat comes in after that.

This directly references their own track "The New Style" from their 1986 debut album *Licensed To Ill*:

> Spent some bank - I got a high powered jumbo
>   Rolled up a wooly and I watched Colombo
>   Let me clear my throat - Kick it over here baby pop
>   And let all the fly skimmies, feel the beat... mmm, drop
>   Coolin' on the corner on a hot summer day
>   Just me, my posse and M.C.A.

From the [3:06 mark](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rrWud7T8q5A#t=3m06s), there's a beat under these first two lines, then no beat under the next two, and again a new beat comes in after the instruction.

To *drop a beat* can also have an opposite, negative meaning in "traditional" live band music, where player or a drummer misses or loses the beat, stopping the rhythm.

Answer (score 3):

To me "[drop the beat](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=drop%20the%20beat)" means someone starts making a good beat so that someone can listen or rap to it.